# How to fix Eclipse ADT Plugin 22.3 / SDK Tools 22.3 with broken properties window?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I recently updated the other day to the latest version of the Android ADT Plugin and SDK Tools which supports Android 4.4 KitKat. When I select a view in the graphical layout editor the properties window fields are not clickable to allow me to type into them nor can I push the 3 dots next to a field.

Using Windows 8.1 64 Bit and Eclipse Keplar. Was working fine until the update.

When looking at the Eclipse Error Log it shows

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.getDefaultProperties(RenderSessionImpl.java:1476)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.getDefaultProperties(BridgeRenderSession.java:68)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.ViewHierarchy.getDefaultProperties(ViewHierarchy.java:710)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.XmlProperty.getStringValue(XmlProperty.java:209)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.XmlProperty.getValue(XmlProperty.java:221)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.XmlPropertyEditor.getText(XmlPropertyEditor.java:116)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.XmlPropertyEditor.paint(XmlPropertyEditor.java:131)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.drawProperty(PropertyTable.java:1309)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.drawContent(PropertyTable.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.handlePaint(PropertyTable.java:1094)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.access$200(PropertyTable.java:64)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable$3.handleEvent(PropertyTable.java:187)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.WM_PRINTCLIENT(Composite.java:1639)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4590)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2440)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button.callWindowProc(Button.java:343)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4989)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2546)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3756)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: A good long-term solution is to switch to Android Studio or IntelliJ for development, because Eclipse is riddled with problems like this, but I realize that might not help in the immediate.

Comment: Agreed. Currently waiting until it gets more stable for work use. Any thoughts on it currently? Use it in a professional environment?

Comment: Just for info: I have Vista 64 bit, Eclipse Indigo and all the latest API 19 upgrades (with the exception of build tools v 19.0.0 which wouldn't build my projects???). I can edit the properties in the graphical layout with plugin 22.3

Comment: I have windows 7 64bits. Juno and API 19 too. I have the same error log. Is there no solution?

Comment: @egfconnor Android Studio is definitely still iffy for non-hobby work, but IntelliJ is fantastic and far more reliable than Eclipse.  Plus it's what Android Studio is based on, so familiarity with it will prepare you for the day that Android Studio is ready.

Comment: @Ricardo Still no solution as far as I know.

Comment: @egfconnor Thanks for the info!. i'm not sure if this is such a big problem. I mean, i can still using XML editor, right?.

Comment: Yes you can @Ricardo. It's just really annoying.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Workaround: switch to Android-18 in Graphical Layout (green Android top-right).

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug with KitKat layout renderer.

Source:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&q=61695%20&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&id=61695

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61715

Answer (score 0):

Switching "android version to use when rendering layouts in eclipse" (green android icon on top right corner) to API 18 saved me after the update!